# Messing with the AutomationId

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin.forms

Is it safe to set the AutomationId of a stack layout in xamarin.forms to find elements of a list view? 
Reason for this:
I have a ComboBox inside of a list view that needs to call on a function with the id of the list view element. When the selection changed the method of the combo box is called, I check the automationId of the parent element of the combo box who's automationId I've set to a unique string from my collection which I can then identify and find where I am in the list.

Question:
Is it safe to do this? Am I breaking some Xamarin.Forms rule or Programming rule?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK I would not suggest that since it could cause issues when the Automation framework tries to search this element If that's why you are doing this go ahead otherwise don't.

When you read the description for [AutomationId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.element.automationid?view=xamarin-forms) it says:

> Gets or sets a value that allows the automation framework to find and interact with this element.
>
> A value that the automation framework can use to find and interact with this element.

More information check [this Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/accessibility/automation-properties)

What I would personally suggest you do is instead of adding this value to your StackLayout why not just add a property to your ComboBox? Like Tag or something and then just find your name by checking that tag?

Comment: Could you give an example as well? Thank you for your answer!

Comment: What kind of an example are expecting?

Comment: How would I add a property to my ComboBox?

Comment: https://mindofai.github.io/Creating-Custom-Controls-with-Bindable-Properties-in-Xamarin.Forms/